# Laravel 7 - cannot fake 3rd party Http call using a Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am trying to use a middleware in Laravel 7 to fake Http calls to a 3rd party API. So I can assign that middleware to any route which will make calls to that 3rd party API. So whenever that route is called, it will call to the faked API.

Purpose of this is, when I want to fake the API, I just only have to assign the middleware to the route. When I don't want to fake the API, I will just remove the middleware from the route.

The middleware looks like below.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class MockApiEndpoints
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // mock api/endpoint
        $vacancies = $this->vacancyRepository->all();
        $url = 'api/endpoint';
        $sessionId = Str::uuid()->toString();
        $response = [
            'result' => 'OK',
            'content' => [
                'suggestedVacancies' => array_map(function ($uid) {
                    return [
                        'id' => $uid,
                        'relevance' => bcdiv(rand(9, 99), 100, 2)
                    ];
                }, $vacancies->pluck('uid')->all()),
                'sessionId' => $sessionId
            ]
        ];
        $this->mockHttpRequest($url, $response);

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function mockHttpRequest(string $uri, $response, int $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {
        $url = config('api.base_url') . '/' . $uri;

        Http::fake([
            $url => Http::response($response, $status, $headers)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Even though I attach this this middleware to the route, route still makes calls to the original API. So the `Htpp::fake` doesn't work in the middleware it seems. `Htpp::fake` does work if I use it inside the controller.

Middleware is attached to the route as below. (Middleware is properly registered in the `$routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernal.php`)

```php
namespace App\Providers;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware(['MockApiEndpoints'])
            ->namespace($this->namespace . '\Api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

I got my work done by using a workaround. But I want to know why does `Http::fake` doesn't work in middleware. Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning $next($request) you should return a response(...) in your middleware.
Perhaps just forward the response from the fake call.

```
return response($responseFrom3rdPartyApiCall, 200);
```

Comment: I cannot return a response in this middleware. The request should go further into the controllers to be processed, which triggers several other actions. I hope you get it.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Thought you wanted to interupt and "proxy" a fake api response from middleware. I dont really see the point in calling a fake API and then just dispose of the answer though. Given that you've imported all classes you use in the middleware it should execute. But how can you tell since its not logging or outputting anything?